# how to build this query using knex

Tags: knex.js

I use knex (homepage: knexjs.org) to select from 3 tables:

- user (id, name, age)
- user_food (user_id, food_id, quantity)
- food (id, name)

Is there anyway to get result like this:

```
[
   {
        user_id: 1,
        name: "john",
        foods: [
            {food_id: 1, name: "pizza", quantity: 2 },
            {food_id: 2, name: "some other food", quantity: 1 },
        ]
   },
   {
        user_id: 2,
        name: "ellen",
        foods: [
            {food_id: 3, name: "humberger", quantity: 1 },
            {food_id: 4, name: "some other food", quantity: 2 },
        ]
   },
]
```

I spent very much time for this, thanks

Comment: Do you know the SQL you would use if you didn't have Knex? 

Since Knex translates js to SQL, if you know the SQL, then we can help with the Knex "translation". And similarly, if you can't do it with SQL, you probably can't do it with (just) Knex.

Comment: thanks for reply, i solved problem by using plain sql query

Comment: It would be great if you would post an answer to your own question for others' benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to break the query apart into multiple queries.

1. Find all users
2. For each user, find their foods

```js
const userFoods = userId =>
  knex('food').select({ foodId: 'food.id' }, 'name', 'user_food.quantity')
  .innerJoin('user_food', 'food.id', 'user_food.food_id')
  .where('user_food.user_id', userId);

const userWithFoods = user =>
  userFoods(user.userId)
  .then(foods => ({ ...user, foods })));

const users = () =>
  knex('user').select({ userId: 'id' }, 'name')
  .then(users => Promise.all(users.map(userWithFoods)));
```

It is possible to write this as a single knex query, but you will need to normalize the data to fit your desired schema.